# When integrating $\int\frac{1}{x^2 +6x +18}$ how to I properly write the partial fraction?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is the problem

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 6x + 18} $$

I know that I can combine the bottom to be $$ (x+3)^2 + 9 $$

which would make my problem look like $$ \int \frac{1}{(x+3)^2 + 9} $$

Would I then be able to do this

$$\int \frac{1}{(x+3)^2 + 9} = \int \left[\frac{A}{x+3} + \frac{Bx+C}{(x+3)^2 + 9}\right] $$

If that is correct, then I can continue with the problem. However, I didn't want to do the rest of the problem if my assumption is incorrect.

**As per Vadim123's & Clayton's suggestion:**

Let 3u = x + 3
$$ \int \frac{du}{(3u)^2 + 9} $$

Pull out $1/9$
$$ \frac{1}{9} \int \frac{du}{u^2 + 1} $$

Now I need to integrate as arctan. I haven't done it before so it might take me a bit before I finish this one up.

Okay, lets try

$$ \frac{1}{9} (u * \arccos(u) - \frac{1}{2} \ln | 1 + u^2 |  ) + c $$

Then change all my $u$'s to $\dfrac{x+3}{3}$

Does that seem correct?

Comment: Nope, your anti derivative is going to be an arctangent. Do you see why??

Comment: See the answer produced by Maple [here](http://rapidshare.com/share/5077A4A67EA24138FBB2A7163F2EB3EC).

Comment: @imranfat After you and a few others pointed it out, I kind of see it. I don't think I would have seen it otherwise though. How do I tell for sure that it will be an inverse trig function other than knowing $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is arctan?

Comment: Ig You try to solve for $A,B,C$ there, you are going to get $A=B=0$ and $C=1$, which is hardly useful. $x+3$ is not a factor of $(x+3)^2+9$.

Comment: If you want to do integration by parts, you have to allow complex numbers: $$\frac{1}{x^2+6x+18} = \frac{A}{x+3+3i} + \frac{B}{x+3-3i}$$ But the other answers are better, using $\arctan$

Comment: Indeed the arctan looks like it'll be the easier way to deal with it. I haven't dealt with complex numbers in a long time. @user64494 It was slightly difficult to follow the steps in that screen, I'm curious, does that software allow you to have it display alternative solutions?

Comment: Here is a thing to look at, if the discriminant b²-4ac of your quadratic term in the denominator is negative, there is no partial fraction decomposition, the result has an arctan in it. (And perhaps a natural log if the numerator as a linear term)

Answer (score 3):

There's no partial fractions here; substitute $3u=x+3$, factor out $\frac{1}{9}$, and integrate as arctangent.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, why 3u rather than just u?

Comment: Because of the 9.

Comment: I've edited my answer, am I on the right track with your statement?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a useful small point that: $$\frac{d(x+3)}{(x+3)^2+9}=\frac{dx}{(x+3)^2+9}$$ since $d(x+3)=(x+3)'\times dx=1\times dx=dx$. Now think again about @vadim123's approach.

Comment: I feel slightly dumb for still not getting this, perhaps it is the notation that I don't understand. This is my best understanding of the explanation: $ 3u = x + 3$ so that : $$\int \frac{1}{(3u)^2 + 9} $$ that way we can pull out $\frac{1}{9}$ from the overall equation making it $\frac{1}{9} \int\frac{dx}{u^2 + 1}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look really closely at your second integral and think of the derivative of $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: You guys are fast! I'll look at it this way and post back with my attempt!

Comment: Any chance you could check my edited answer?

Comment: @ConfusingCalc: You are fairly close on your edited answer, but you don't quite have it. A more suggestive hint: $$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$Does this help clear things up?

Comment: Not quite, I assumed since the sign of both the denominators was positive that it didn't matter. Sorry, I am quite new to dealing with inverse trig functions (I missed a few lectures due to medical issues) and am reading up on them now. I'm attempting to absorb as much knowledge as I can.